# What is CentOS 7 Apache reverse proxy?

Tags: vpn, centos, apache-http-server, proxy, plesk

I have some videos on my website videos but they are IP address protected.

My users need to use my smart DNS or my own VPN to run the videos.

Or I was using https://github.com/joshdick/miniProxy.

miniProxy can't handle too many users and I am getting a PHP time out error.

```
problem php-fpm (70007)The timeout specified has expired: AH01075: Er
```

Can a reverse proxy change user IP address to server IP address?

Or I am looking at a simple mirror proxy like torrent sites use for unblocking their sites?

Or tv channel sites?

Can I post a videos examples here?

Sorry my  English is not good.

I am using DigitalOcean CentOS 7 with Plesk.

All I want is to change user IP address to my server IP address without using my VPN or smart DNS.

Comment: Please note: I have made some minor updates to your post, including changing "reserve" proxy to "reverse" proxy (which is what I believe you are intending to ask about). If this is incorrect, please re-edit the question and add some additional details about any "reserve" proxy you are encountering or wish to configure.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a reverse proxy change a user IP address to a server IP address?

A reverse proxy passes incoming traffic directed at itself to another server and vice versa, once a connection is established.

So if you had PC1 (your user), PC2 (your reverse proxy) and PC3 (your video server):

1. PC1 (User) would contact PC2 (Proxy).
2. PC2 (Proxy) would contact PC3 (Video Server) and ask for whatever PC1 (User) wanted.
3. PC3 (Video Server) would return e.g. a video to PC2 (Proxy).
4. PC2 (Proxy) would pass that video back to PC1 (User).

> All I want is to change the user IP address to my server IP address [.]

If you configure your video server to allow access from your reverse proxy, you likely should be able to do what (I believe) you want.